# vue3 siblings communication: issue with consistency

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

#### Context

In my Vue 3 app, I have a HomeView component that contains the following template:

```js
  <InputsComponent></InputsComponent>
  <CheckboxesComponent></CheckboxesComponent>
  <Toolsbar></Toolsbar>
```

InputsComponent displays a series of text inputs, while CheckboxesComponent does the same with checkboxes.

Toolsbar contains a series of buttons, one of which is "reset".

The focus of this question is on sibling components communication.

#### What I need to achieve

After a user fills in some inputs and/or clicks on some of the checkboxes, if I press the reset button in Toolsbar I need the inputs in both InputsComponent and CheckboxesComponent to reset, and for the user to be able to fill the inputs again and reset them at will. The exact logic of how the components achieve the resetting is out of scope, what matters is how to coordinate the communication between the three components.

#### What I know

I'm trying to avoid using EventBus as it is discouraged in Vue 3.

#### What I've tried

I tried having the parent act as bridge for communication, so:

ToolsBar.vue

```js
<button @click="$emit('reset')"> Reset </button>
```

HomeView.vue

```js
<script setup>
const state = reactive({
  resetRequested: false
})

function requestReset() {
  state.resetRequested = true;
}

</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <InputsComponent :reset-requested="state.resetRequested"></InputsComponent>
    <CheckboxesComponent :reset-requested="state.resetRequested"></CheckboxesComponent>
    <Toolsbar @reset="requestReset()"></Toolsbar>
  </main>
</template>
```

InputsComponent.vue

```js
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    resetRequested: boolean,
})

watch(
  () => props.resetRequested,
  (resetRequested) => {
    if (resetRequested == true)
        //reset the inputs
  }
)

</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <input type="text" /> //and a lot more of these
  </main>
</template>
```

the CheckboxesComponent works the same, but displays and resets checkboxes.

so far it works as intended, but I cannot hit the reset button again, as the prop is stuck to `true`. So I tried having InputsComponent send an event of its own to the parent, and in response the parent would then set the prop to false, but that broke the behavior altogether

#### Where I'm stuck

Is there really no better way to achieve this than this bouncing back and forth between children and their parent? (the same, I believe, would apply to using a store)

I end up with:

- Toolsbar sending an event to HomeView
- HomeView setting a prop to CheckboxesComponent and InputsComponent
- CheckboxesComponent and InputsComponent reacting to the prop and doing their work, then sending an event back to HomeView
- HomeView resetting the props of CheckboxesComponent and InputsComponent so they're ready to begin the cycle anew

Setting aside the fact that I couldn't make it work, this all seems a bit too convoluted to me.

Even more so when you consider that this way, I'd need to either take for granted that both CheckboxesComponent and InputsComponent get reset at the same time (when one tells the parent that they're done, the parent's state is changed and so do everyone's props) or give the parent a different state variable for every child it needs to talk to (which in another scenario could potentially be dozens).

What am I missing? Is this the process I should try to make work, or is there something better I could leverage?

Comment: `resetRequested` seems useless to me. Why not pass a function which actually resets the state (e.g: the input data)? But you got the pattern right. In order to share data in real time, the reactive data needs to be external to the components using it. The store pattern is less verbose because you import the store instead of dealing with props and emits. Regardless if the *"store"* is an actual pinia store or a reactive object. The only reason you'd use props is if the parents would be rendered in a list and each would need to pass its state to its children to be modified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to considerate an store to solve comunnication between sibling components, like:

`stores/form.js`

```js
export const form = ref({
    field1: '',
    field2: '',
    resetFields() {
        this.field1= '';
        this.field2= '';
    }
});
```

`ToolsBar.vue`

```js
import {form} from "../stores/form.js"

// ...

<button @click="form.resetFields()"> Reset </button>
```

`InputsComponent.vue`

```js
<script setup>
import {form} from "../stores/form.js"

</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <input type="text" v-model="form.field1" /> 
  </main>
</template>
```

However, for large application it's better to use an state managment like pinia.